# Dataflow: Apache Beam WARNING: apache_beam.utils.retry:Retry with exponential backoff:

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a simple pipeline, which 3 weeks ago would work fine but I've gone back to the code to enhance it and when I tried to run the code it returned the following error:

**WARNING:apache_beam.utils.retry:Retry with exponential backoff: waiting for 10.280192286716229 seconds before retrying exists because we caught exception: TypeError: string indices must be integers
Traceback for above exception (most recent call last):**

I am running the dataflow script via Cloud Shell on the Google Cloud Platform. By simply executing Python3 <dataflow.py>

The code is as follows, and this used to submit the job to dataflow without issue

```
import json
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, StandardOptions
from apache_beam import coders

pipeline_args=[
      '--runner=DataflowRunner',
      '--job_name=my-job-name',
      '--project=my-project-id',
      '--region=europe-west2',
      '--temp_location=gs://mybucket/temp',
      '--staging_location=gs://mybucket/staging'
    ]

options = PipelineOptions (pipeline_args)
p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
rows = (
        p | 'Read daily Spot File' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(
                     file_pattern='gs://bucket/filename.gz', 
                    compression_type='gzip',
                    coder=coders.BytesCoder(),
                    skip_header_lines=0))

p.run()
```

Any advice as to why this has started happening would be great to know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you do after 'Read daily Spot File'? That error message seems to come from somewhere else.

Comment: can you show the traceback as well?

Comment: If you are still experiencing this behavior, it would be useful to have the full traceback indeed.

Comment: BTW, I just ran your code successfully so we definitely need to see more code (if it isn't all there) or the traceback to be able to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the original issue but I can speak to Usman's post which seems to describe an issue I ran into myself.

Python doesn't use gcloud auth to authenticate but it uses the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. So before you run the python command to launch the Dataflow job, you will need to set that environment variable:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/key"
```

More info on setting up the environment variable: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable

Then you'll have to make sure that the account you set up has the necessary permissions in your GCP project.

Permissions and service accounts:

- User service account or user account: it needs the Dataflow Admin
  role at the project level and to be able to act as the worker service
  account (source:
  https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#worker_service_account).
- Worker service account: it will be one worker service account per
  Dataflow pipeline. This account will need the Dataflow Worker role at
  the project level plus the necessary permissions to the resources
  accessed by the Dataflow pipeline (source:
  https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#worker_service_account).
  Example: if Dataflow pipeline’s input is Pub/Sub topic and output is
  BigQuery table, the worker service account will need read access to
  the topic as well as write permission to the BQ table.
- Dataflow service account: this is the account that gets automatically
  created when you enable the Dataflow API in a project. It
  automatically gets the Dataflow Service Agent role at the project
  level (source:
  https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#service_account).

Answer (score 0):

I found same kind of error following this [tutorial][1]

```
python3 PubSubToGCS.py \


 --project=mango-s-11-a81277cf  \
  --region=us-east1 \
  --input_topic=projects/mango-s-11-a81277cf/topics/pubsubtest \
  --output_path=gs://mangobucket001/samples/output \
  --runner=DataflowRunner \
  --window_size=2 \
  --num_shards=2 \
  --temp_location=gs://mangobucket001/temp


a81277cf/topics/pubsubtest   --output_path=gs://mangobucket001/   --runner=DataflowRunner   --window_size=2   --num_shards=2   --temp_location=gs://mangobucket001/temp
    INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.stager:Downloading source distribution of the SDK from PyPi
    INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.stager:Executing command: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', 'download', '--dest', '/tmp/tmpaelpxw64', 'apache-beam==2.33.0', '--no-deps', '--no-binary', ':all:']
    INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.stager:Staging SDK sources from PyPI: dataflow_python_sdk.tar
    INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.stager:Downloading binary distribution of the SDK from PyPi
    INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.stager:Executing command: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', 'download', '--dest', '/tmp/tmpaelpxw64', 'apache-beam==2.33.0', '--no-deps', '--only-binary', ':all:', '--python-version', '38', '--implementation', 'cp', '--abi', 'cp38', '--platform', 'manylinux1_x86_64']
    INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.stager:Staging binary distribution of the SDK from PyPI: apache_beam-2.33.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
    WARNING:root:Make sure that locally built Python SDK docker image has Python 3.8 interpreter.
    INFO:root:Default Python SDK image for environment is apache/beam_python3.8_sdk:2.33.0
    INFO:root:Using provided Python SDK container image: gcr.io/cloud-dataflow/v1beta3/python38-fnapi:2.33.0
    INFO:root:Python SDK container image set to "gcr.io/cloud-dataflow/v1beta3/python38-fnapi:2.33.0" for Docker environment
    INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient:Defaulting to the temp_location as staging_location: gs://mangobucket001/temp
    INFO:apache_beam.internal.gcp.auth:Setting socket default timeout to 60 seconds.
    INFO:apache_beam.internal.gcp.auth:socket default timeout is 60.0 seconds.
    INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient:Starting GCS upload to gs://mangobucket001/temp/beamapp-maan-0214122440-788240.1644841480.788658/pickled_main_session...
    INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
    INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
    INFO:oauth2client.transport:Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
    INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
    WARNING:apache_beam.utils.retry:Retry with exponential backoff: waiting for 3.054787201157167 seconds before retrying _gcs_file_copy because we caught exception: OSError: Could not upload to GCS path gs://mangobucket001/temp/beamapp-maan-0214122440-788240.1644841480.788658: access denied. Please verify that credentials are valid and that you have write access to the specified path.
     Traceback for above exception (most recent call last):
      File "/home/maan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 253, in wrapper
        return fun(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/maan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/apiclient.py", line 559, in _gcs_file_copy
        self.stage_file(to_folder, to_name, f, total_size=total_size)
      File "/home/maan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/apiclient.py", line 642, in stage_file
        raise IOError((
    
    INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient:Starting GCS upload to gs://mangobucket001/temp/beamapp-maan-0214122440-788240.1644841480.788658/pickled_main_session...
    WARNING:apache_beam.utils.retry:Retry with exponential backoff: waiting for 5.22755214575824 seconds before retrying _gcs_file_copy because we caught exception: OSError: Could not upload to GCS path gs://mangobucket001/temp/beamapp-maan-0214122440-788240.1644841480.788658: access denied. Please verify that credentials are valid and that you have write access to the specified path.
     Traceback for above exception (most recent call last):
      File "/home/maan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 253, in wrapper
        return fun(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/maan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/apiclient.py", line 559, in _gcs_file_copy
        self.stage_file(to_folder, to_name, f, total_size=total_size)
      File "/home/maan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/apiclient.py", line 642, in stage_file
        raise IOError((
    
    INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient:Starting GCS upload to gs://mangobucket001/temp/beamapp-maan-0214122440-788240.1644841480.788658/pickled_main_session...
    WARNING:apache_beam.utils.retry:Retry with exponential backoff: waiting for 19.20582351652022 seconds before retrying _gcs_file_copy because we caught exception: OSError: Could not upload to GCS path gs://mangobucket001/temp/beamapp-maan-0214122440-788240.1644841480.788658: access denied. Please verify that credentials are valid and that you have write access to the specified path.
     Traceback for above exception (most recent call last):
      File "/home/maan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 253, in wrapper
        return fun(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/maan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/apiclient.py", line 559, in _gcs_file_copy
        self.stage_file(to_folder, to_name, f, total_size=total_size)
      File "/home/maan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/apiclient.py", line 642, in stage_file
        raise IOError((
    
    INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient:Starting GCS upload to gs://mangobucket001/temp/beamapp-maan-0214122440-788240.1644841480.788658/pickled_main_session...
    WARNING:apache_beam.utils.retry:Retry with exponential backoff: waiting for 39.51226214946517 seconds before retrying _gcs_file_copy because we caught exception: OSError: Could not upload to GCS path gs://mangobucket001/temp/beamapp-maan-0214122440-788240.1644841480.788658: access denied. Please verify that credentials are valid and that you have write access to the specified path.
     Traceback for above exception (most recent call last):
      File "/home/maan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 253, in wrapper
        return fun(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/maan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/apiclient.py", line 559, in _gcs_file_copy
        self.stage_file(to_folder, to_name, f, total_size=total_size)
      File "/home/maan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/apiclient.py", line 642, in stage_file
        raise IOError((
    
    INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient:Starting GCS upload to gs://mangobucket001/temp/beamapp-maan-0214122440-788240.1644841480.788658/pickled_main_session...
    WARNING:apache_beam.utils.retry:Retry with exponential backoff: waiting for 61.15550203875504 seconds before retrying _gcs_file_copy because we caught exception: OSError: Could not upload to GCS path gs://mangobucket001/temp/beamapp-maan-0214122440-788240.1644841480.788658: access denied. Please verify that credentials are valid and that you have write access to the specified path.
     Traceback for above exception (most recent call last):
      File "/home/maan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 253, in wrapper
        return fun(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/maan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/apiclient.py", line 559, in _gcs_file_copy
        self.stage_file(to_folder, to_name, f, total_size=total_size)
      File "/home/maan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/apiclient.py", line 642, in stage_file
        raise IOError((
    
    INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient:Starting GCS upload to gs://mangobucket001/temp/beamapp-maan-0214122440-788240.1644841480.788658/pickled_main_session...
    WARNING:apache_beam.utils.retry:Retry with exponential backoff: waiting for 122.46460946846845 seconds before retrying _gcs_file_copy because we caught exception: OSError: Could not upload to GCS path gs://mangobucket001/temp/beamapp-maan-0214122440-788240.1644841480.788658: access denied. Please verify that credentials are valid and that you have write access to the specified path.
     Traceback for above exception (most recent call last):
      File "/home/maan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 253, in wrapper
        return fun(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/maan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/apiclient.py", line 559, in _gcs_file_copy
        self.stage_file(to_folder, to_name, f, total_size=total_size)
      File "/home/maan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/apiclient.py", line 642, in stage_file
    
    
      [1]: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pubsub-dataflow
```